# How to create a context menu on a MenuItem of a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, contextmenu, navigation-drawer

I would like to open a context menu on some of my navigation drawer MenuItems (in order to display dynamically created lists of items to select from). But I cannot find out which view to use for `registerForContextMenu`, nor do I know which view to pass to `openContextMenu` manually (e.g., if I want the context menu also to show up on a single click). Simply using the MenuItem identifier won't work, since it cannot be cast to a View. So how can I use a context menu here?

Comment: Is this some sort of homework/app work? I've seen the exact same question not long ago. I'll give you the same advice I gave on the other question, rethink your logic: you really shouldn't start context menus for menu items as that isn't what  the vast majority of user would expect to happen.

Comment: I have seen users discussing the same thing about action bar menu items, so why wouldn't you consider doing the same for drawer menu items? 
Considering not everyone who is developing is a full-blown Android expert yet (and some may even dare to try getting better at it by working on a "real" app instead of a homework), could you give more concrete suggestions on what other approaches serve here? I tried using submenus, but as far as I understand from reading several posts here I can't easily uninflate/reinflate them, so my drawer menu gets unhandy with permanently open submenus.

Comment: I recommended against it because it's not what the widget was built for(like providing navigation through your app and not show arbitrary stuff like ContextMenu). Instead, from the little information you provided, I would recommend replacing the NavigationView with an ExpandableListView, this way you'll have the "main options"(your current menu options) and when the user clicks those you'll show the child views(your lists of data) below it providing some structure to the way you show the data.

Comment: I am using the navigation drawer for navigation through my app, but would need the submenus for this to work the way I plan. If I understand the information on using an Expandable ListView correctly, this will mean a lot of manual reimplementation, for something that seemed like a rather straightforward functionality. While I will look into this again, I would still like to have certainty: So is using a context menu on the drawer items just not recommended, or impossible (without basically reimplementing my own drawer)?

Answer (score 0):

One way I ended up succeeding to do this is by registering the entire NavigationView for context menu and keeping track of which menuItem was selected by storing this in an internal member variable whenever an item is clicked/long clicked, before manually invoking `openContextMenu` on the NavigationView. Then it is possible to implement `onCreateContextMenu` only for those MenuItems for which I actually require the context menu.

More specifically, I register the drawer for context menu like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_menu, menu);
    NavigationView nav_draw = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (nav_draw != null) {
        registerForContextMenu(nav_draw);
    }
    return true;
}
```

I introduce a member variable

```
private MenuItem _lastNavDrawerMenuItemSelected = null;
```

which I keep at null whenever none of the "interesting" menu items are selected, otherwise I store in it the calling menu item and manually open the context menu:

```
public void inflateSubMenu(MenuItem item) {
    NavigationView v = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    if (v != null) {
        _lastNavDrawerMenuItemSelected = item;
        openContextMenu(v);
    }
}
```

In `onCreateContextMenu`, I make sure that only the desired MenuItems get handled, pass on the ID of the NavigationView and current MenuItem as `groupId` and `itemId`, and set the internal member variable back to `null`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId() == R.id.nav_view) {
        if (_lastNavDrawerMenuItemSelected != null) {
            if (_lastNavDrawerMenuItemSelected.getItemId() == R.id.my_submenu_item_id) {
              menu.setHeaderTitle(...);
              menu.add(v.getId(),_lastNavDrawerMenuItemSelected.getItemId(), Menu.NONE, <ENTRY TITLE>);
              ...
            }
            _lastNavDrawerMenuItemSelected = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I implement the necessary actions based on `groupId` (which I set to the NavigationView above) and `itemId` (which I set to the MenuItem for which the context menu was built):

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getGroupId() == R.id.nav_view) {
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.my_submenu_item_id) {
           ...
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```